# Oracle Discoverer 3.1

Tags: oracle

> "Invalid join configuration - includes a master with two separately
>   joined detail folders"

Hi. The above message appears on some of the PCs but not others, although all have WinXP installed and access the very same data.. . How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle help is pretty detailed here:

> Action: Construct the join so that the folder specified as the master actually contains the master key and the folders specified as detail actually contain the detail keys. If the join you are creating is necessary, create a complex folder to hide one of the joins. This is normally only the case where the relationship between the folders is one-to-one, and there is no actual master folder.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/core.1111/e10113/chapter_bi_svr_messages.htm

Comment: That's out of the question. The system has been there for years and not all PCs have the same problem. I want to know what's wrong with the ones that exhibit the problem and whether something can be done to solve it.. . Thanks. (-;